# Send mail as attachment in .eml extension instead of .msg from Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Is it possible to attach a mail from Outlook in .eml format? By default, mails will be attached as .msg files.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to save email to EML file first and then attach it to a new email. Unfortunatelly, there is no built-in functionality in Outlook to save messages to EML format. Fortunatelly, there is a free [Export Messages to EML Files](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/outlookmessagesexporteml) add-in you can use to save any message to EML right from Outlook.

DISCLAIMER: I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.